# Como criar relacionamento 1-N em classe com mais de uma propriedade e mesmo subtipo?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de classes, nada convencional mas é no molde que preciso para resolver meu problema:

Árvore:

```cs
public class Arvore
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Galho_TipoA> Galhos_TipoA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Galho_TipoB> Galhos_TipoB { get; set; }
}
```

Galho:

```cs
public class Galho
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ArvoreId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ArvoreId")]
    public Arvore Avore { get; set; }
}

public class Galho_TipoA : Galho { }
public class Galho_TipoB : Galho { }
```

Ao gerar meu schema estou obtendo o seguinte:

```cs
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Arvores",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Descricao = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
        
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Galhos",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            ArvoreId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            Descricao = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
            Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            Arvore_Id = c.Int(),
            Arvore_Id1 = c.Int(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Arvores", t => t.Arvore_Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Arvores", t => t.Arvore_Id1)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Arvores", t => t.ArvoreId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.ArvoreId)
    .Index(t => t.Arvore_Id)
    .Index(t => t.Arvore_Id1);
```

Notem que está sendo gerado vários índices para as propriedades de `Arvore` que são do mesmo tipo:

```cs
.ForeignKey("dbo.Arvores", t => t.Arvore_Id)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Arvores", t => t.Arvore_Id1)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Arvores", t => t.ArvoreId, cascadeDelete: true)
.Index(t => t.ArvoreId)
.Index(t => t.Arvore_Id)
.Index(t => t.Arvore_Id1);
```

Criei os tipos `Galho_TipoA` e `Galho_TipoB` exatamente para diferenciar os registros pelo campo `Discriminator`, mas não funcionou. Em vez de apontar para `ArvoreId` criaram outros, um para cada propriedade em `Arvore`.

**Como resolver essa questão para `ArvoreId` e não ser preciso gerar o outros?**
**Ou, qual seria a forma correta de estruturar esse esquema?**

---

## Edição

A nessecidade de lógica que o modelo precisa atender é a seguinte: Uma `Arvore` pode ter vários `Galhos` de diversos tipos.
Por isso pensei nos tipos como propriedades separadas.

Comment: Eu não entendi bem qual o propósito se puder colocar qual eu melhora a resposta ou até coloco outra resposta! achei essa interessante e o efeito funcionou realmente com discrimator dos dois lados

Comment: Não é mais fácil colocar o tipo do galho, então?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema não tem tanto a ver com a derivação de classes, e sim pelo fato de você ter duas `ICollection` cujo tipo base é o mesmo (no caso, `Galho`). Isto cria certa ambiguidade na hora do Entity Framework montar a sentença, pois ele pode perfeitamente popular uma `ICollection` do tipo A com dados do tipo B, mesmo que haja o `Discriminator` definido.

Aparentemente não é uma falha de Design, e sim uma falta de recurso do próprio Entity Framework. O que normalmente se faz [é aceitar as duas colunas e mapeá-las com nomes melhores usando a Fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083296/entity-framework-generated-column-names).

Comment: Desculpa, não tem falha no Entity Framework, ele é baseado nas formas Normais, e essa forma que ele ta querendo não tem mesmo!

Comment: Eu escrevi **falta**, não **falha**.

Comment: você não pode falar nem falta, se o Entity Framework é baseado nas formas normais deve ser seguido assim...! não é falta de nada! me desculpe mas, está errado!

Answer (score 2):

Efeito esperado diante a pergunta, não é uma boa prática, mas, segui o questionamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```
[Table("Arvore")]
public class Arvore
{
    public Arvore() { }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ArvoreId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

}
public class ArvoreA : Arvore 
{
    public ArvoreA()
    {
        this.Galho = new HashSet<Galho>();
    }
    [ForeignKey("ArvoreId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Galho> Galho { get; set; }
}
public class ArvoreB : Arvore 
{
    public ArvoreB()
    {
        this.Galho = new HashSet<Galho>();
    }
    [ForeignKey("ArvoreId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Galho> Galho { get; set; }
}
[Table("Galho")]
public class Galho
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int GalhoId { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ArvoreId { get; set; }

}
public class GalhoA : Galho 
{        
    [ForeignKey("ArvoreId")]
    public virtual Arvore Arvore { get; set; }
}
public class GalhoB : Galho 
{        
    [ForeignKey("ArvoreId")]
    public virtual Arvore Arvore { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        :base("Con") {
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    }
    public DbSet<Arvore> Arvore { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Galho> Galho { get; set; }

}
```

---

```
using (Context ctx = new Context())
{
    //ArvoreA arvore = new ArvoreA();
    //arvore.Descricao = "Arvore 3";                
    //arvore.Galho.Add(new GalhoA() { Descricao = "Galho 3" });                
    //ctx.Arvore.Add(arvore);

    //ArvoreA arvore = ctx.Arvore.OfType<ArvoreA>().Where(x => x.ArvoreId == 1).FirstOrDefault();
    //arvore.Galho.Add(new GalhoA() { Descricao = "Galho 1" });

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Ok, @TiagoSilva